# Difference between Image layer and Tile Layer

Tags: openlayers, terminology, tile-layer

what is the basic difference between Image Layer and Tile Layer? Apart from the documentation....which says below points

**ol/layer/Tile** - Renders sources that provide **tiled images in grids** that are **organized by zoom levels** for specific resolutions.
**ol/layer/Image** - Renders sources that provide **map images at arbitrary extents** and resolutions.

Link to above documentation is https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/concepts.html

Comment: See concept of map tiles: https://www.maptiler.com/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/

Answer (score 0):

do you know about tile?
a tile layer will req many times, each time get one tile. Finally, tile layer put tiles together into a image.
a img layer only req image once, and it will show the image directly